# How to know Thread Life time using JVM parameter

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, monitoring

Is there any JVM parameter or configuration to print how much time taken by each thread in Java?

It's not possible for me to go in each Servlet and get start/end time of method execution and then print difference.

Please suggest me any good idea which can be implemented once and reflect in all over the application.

Comment: Did you consider using a profiler for this purpose? 
see [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler)

Comment: What is the use case? Why do you want this? Logging, profiling, monitoring etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trace your threads activity using JVM command line you can use `-Xrunhprof`.

For example :

> java -Xrunhprof:file=dump.hprof,thread=y,monitor=y Main

Then take a look at the file `dump.hprof`, it's a bit hard to read but you can obtain accurate informations.

Also see :

> java -Xrunhprof:help

If you need the list of all the options.

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

[ThreadMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) might be a good place to start if you can add your code to do it.